# Problem with SELECT CASE WHEN THEN, 0 result

Tags: mysql, select, case

Need an advice in  SELECT CASE WHEN THEN. In main, removed all unimportant function, usual `select i.fav_id FROM users;` i see original table:

```
fav_id
1
2
6
7
```

but i need change some id's for result will be:

```
fav_id
1
3
6
8
```

i do:

```
SELECT i.fav_id = 
        CASE 
           WHEN 2 THEN 3
           WHEN 3 THEN 2
           WHEN 7 THEN 8
           WHEN 8 THEN 7
           ELSE i.fav_id
       END fav_id
FROM `favorites` AS i WHERE i.member = '123456'
```

i got:

```
fav_id
0
0
0
0
```

i'm new to select CASE selection but after searching alot manuals and examples, and did not fund how to solve my problem. thanx for your time !

```
used:
libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 
PHP: 5.6.28-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
phpMyAdmin  4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu2
```

Comment: select case WHEN THEN  can be solved in different times, you can show you answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution, sorry, my mistake !

```
SELECT i.fav_id, 
        CASE 
           WHEN i.fav_id = 2 THEN 3
           WHEN i.fav_id = 3 THEN 2
           WHEN i.fav_id = 7 THEN 8
           WHEN i.fav_id = 8 THEN 7
           ELSE i.fav_id
       END fav_id
FROM `favorites` AS i WHERE i.member = '123456'
```

Comment: yes. and good to change one of the fav_id to the other name, or it will be returned as fav_id, fav_id(2)

Comment: There are two different syntaxes of CASE (the expression). Using SQL Server terminology (because MySQL doesn't have any names for the two variations), the expression in your answer uses the *searched* CASE syntax. The one you attempted in your question is a *simple* CASE, and it requires the `i.fav_id` to go directly after the `CASE` keyword: `CASE i.fav_id WHEN 2 THEN 3 WHEN 3 THEN 2 … ELSE i.fav_id END`.

Comment: i have remove unnecessarily data, makes it simply to understand main problem. p.s. thanx for your comment !